# How to validate both integer and decimal values using regular expression?

Tags: jquery, regex

Tring Allow to both `Integer` as well as `Decimal` as input. And restricting on total length which should not be greater that 11(MaximumLength of input including decimal point)
eg. Allowed values are
    1.0, 1.123546, 12345678912,12.12345678,...etc.
i.e. If value contain `Decimal` point then allow at least one `digit` after `Decimal` point otherwise allow complete integer number with maximum length i.e. 11

I have declared regular expression as:
`/^-?(([0-9]{0,11}) | ([0-9]{0,9}.[0-9]{1,2}))$/`

And the values I'm testing against as: 6666666.666

But the result always not getting matched.

NOTE: If length of digit before decimal point is 7 then allow 3 digit after decimal point in case Maximum allowed length is 11.
      `Fractional` part length decided based on `integral` part.

------------------------ JQuery Function-----------------------------------

```
function Validate(sender, precision)
{
    var variable;
    if (precision != "0") 
    {
        var valueLength = sender.value.indexOf('.');
        if (sender.id.indexOf("Longitude") > -1)
            variable = "-?[0-9,]{0," + parseInt($(sender).attr("data-length") - (parseInt(precision) + 1)) + "}[.][0-9]{0," + parseInt(precision) + "}$";
        else
        variable = "-?(([0-9]{0," + parseInt($(sender).attr("data-length")) + "})|([0-9]{0," + parseInt($(sender).attr("data-length") - 2) + "}.[0-9]{1," + parseInt

        ($(sender).attr("data-length") - (valueLength + 2)) + "}))$";
    }
    else
        variable = "-?[0-9,]{0," + parseInt($(sender).attr("data-length")) + "}$";
        var re = new RegExp('^' + variable);
    if (sender.value != "") 
    {
        if (!re.test(sender.value)) 
        {
            alert('Not Matched');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Matched');
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Are the spaces around the alternation a copy/paste error? if not, remove them.

Comment: Why not check the length separately? `if ((sender.value+"").length <= 11)`

Comment: Well what about [`^(\d(?:\.\d)?){1,11}$`](https://regex101.com/r/sW4nS0/1)

Comment: @Uchiha this is nice!

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble

Comment: @Uchiha, can you split your expression and explain I'm new to lookahead concept and not understand, please...!

Comment: @Uchiha nice but seems not exactly what he need, as it [also matches like those: `123.11.11.0000000`, `12345678910.1`](https://regex101.com/r/aY6cT4/1) but interesting approach!

Comment: Yep its not what he's looking for @bobblebubble

Comment: @Kaishu its not a lookahead concept its simply a group capturing

Comment: @Uchiha, ok. Here is what I'm doing 
`variable = "-?(\d(?:\.\d)?){1,11}$";
var re = new RegExp('^' + variable);
if (!re.test(sender.value)){//Not matched}else{Matched}` But seems to not working. It that wrong.?

Comment: @kaishu check the link to my answer there you can find `code generator` under `Tools` section on left hand side you can copy your code over there as from your code it seems to be not going to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use regex only, an idea is to use a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for checking max length.

```
^-?(?!.{12})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

- `^-?` an [optional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) hyphen at [`^` start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `(?!.{12})` the lookahead checks if there's not  more than 11 of [any characters](http://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot) ahead.
- `\d+` matches one or more `\d` which is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for digit `[0-9]`
- `(?:\.\d+)?` followed by an optional [group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) containing a dot followed by one or more digits.
- `$` matches the end

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mU4eL4/2)

Comment: I have insert above mentioned expression in function I've put above but still `re.test(sender.value)` always returning false...

Comment: @Kaishu Try `/^-?(?!.{12})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(sender.value)` [works fine (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/osfdrw4p/).

Comment: this works, so what is the problem in function where I'm using this.?

Comment: @Kaishu If you use with `new RegExp` need more escaping: `var re = new RegExp('^-?(?!.{12})\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$');` [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osfdrw4p/1/).

Answer (score 2):

First, `.` is a special character in a regular expression which matches ***any*** character, so your expression matches more than you're expecting.

More importantly, you're explicitly looking for `{0,9}` characters before the decimal and `{0,2}` after it, and the example you gave of `6666666.666` has more than two decimals.

Why not simply

```
if (/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/.test( sender.value ) && sender.value.length <= 11) ...
```

Let the regex worry about the numbers and formatting and deal with the length separately. Length is ***easy*** to check without mucking around with regex variations.

Comment: This is ok for other fields but there are another fields like `latitude` and `longitude` where I'm restricting user with the format as 99.999999999 and 999.999999999999 respectively but this condition allows those fields to take integral part more that 2 and three digit for lat and long... How to handle these combine condition.?

Comment: You cannot have a single test for both "any number of digits before or after the decimal as long as the total length is 11 or fewer characters" and "any number of characters long but with only two or three digits before the decimal". Write one test for one and a completely separate test for the other. (In the latter case it's `/^[0-9]{2,3}(\.[0-9]+)$/`)

Comment: I don't know why it allowing value as (`111.`) . As we have restricted to insert atleast one digit after decimal point still it allows empty fractional part after decimal point.

Comment: My expression explicitly ends with `?` so the decimal component is not required. If you need it to be required, don't use a `?` there.